# Setting External Hard Drive spin-down / standby / sleep / idle time

Tags: external-hard-drive, sleep, time, standby

I've got two external hard drives, an Adata (with Toshiba HDD in it) and a Seagate branded HDD. The Adata automatically switch off or goes to sleep mode after 10 minutes of inactivity (even the indicator LED is switched off, the manufacturer set it, I haven't done anything with it) while the Seagate keeps spinning until it's connected. I used to not to disconnect my external HDD and with my Adata HDD it wasn't a problem, but I have to disconnect my new Seagate HDD otherwise it will wear out very fast.

How can I set the spin-down / standby / sleep / idle time for an external HDD? I want a solution in which case the setting is saved to the HDD's PCB, so it will standby after x minutes if I connect it to an other computer too, so no programs needed to run in the background to do this.

I changed its APM settings with CrystakDiskInfo and Victoria and it worked, but it did not saved the changes permanently (and the indicator LED is not turning off), so if the program stops the APM settings change back to default. And an other problem is that I set the APM to 127 or 7F and it standby after 1 minute what I find very few, if I know it well it has to standby after around 10 minutes with this value.

Both HDD's APM settings are the same, so Adata did it in another way.

Or how can I access the Adata's settings, so I could just copy them and set my Seagate HDD the same way.